# Hide Default Video Shortcode Controls on PageLoad

Tags: shortcode, media, media-library

In wordpress 3.6+ when we use default video shortcode `[video]`, controls of video are always visible on pageload. How can we hide these controls on page load and show only when we hover over the video element.

Using the CSS code below, does the trick ...

```
.wp-video .mejs-container .mejs-controls {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

But, controls wont show on hovering then. How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the hover CSS code to enable it e.g.

```
.mejs-container .mejs-controls:hover {
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: oh yeah, some times pretty straight forward solution dont come to your mind. Thnx for the direction. But actual code should be something like this: `.wp-video:hover .mejs-container .mejs-controls {
 display: block;
 visibility: visible;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
.wp-video:not(:hover) .mejs-container .mejs-controls {
    visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;
}
```

This way, only showing controls on hover ;)